# What to do when facing design invisibility issue in android studio?

Tags: android-studio

[image: Screenshot]

This is being displayed on the screen. It is happening after I am running a project made on someone else's PC. It is not the case with my projects.

Comment: Try to Change the Theme for Preview "OurMeal" TO "AppTheme"

Comment: How should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can refresh the layout in the Design-Tab. If it won't show either, you will probably getting some layout errors. This means that you did something incorrectly while creating your layout. Android Studio will tell you the Error, so that you can fix your layout.

Oh and as @Himanshu Sharma noted, you are probably using the wrong Theme. Change this theme to AppTheme and this will likely solve your Problem.